# What is the mean value of a pair of Ramanujan Sums when summed over squares?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, exponential-sums

Does anyone know of the mean value of two Ramanujan Sums when summed over the square of integers?

In my research on the [Landau problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau's_problems) regarding nearly square primes, I have run into the mean value of a product of [Ramanujan Sums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan's_sum):
\begin{equation*}
\lim\limits_{N \to \infty}
\frac{1}{N}
\sum\limits_{n =1}^{N} 
c_r\left( n^2 \right)
c_s\left( n^2 \right)
\end{equation*}

Does anyone know of a listing of properties of Ramanujan Sums similar to the [this one](http://washburnresearch.org/NumberTheory/PropertiesOfRamanujanSums.pdf), but with summations taken over the squares of positive numbers instead summation over the integers?

The closest I can find is the function, $E_G$ found in [Sums of products of Ramanujan sums](http://arxiv.org/abs/1104.1906) by Toth. I am interested in the particular case where $g_1(n) = n^2$ though and not general case case represented by $E_G$ for and arbitrary set of functions $g_i(n)$

Comment: I have now calculated the mean value in general, see the Added section.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a partial answer (**Added:** completed below). Assuming $(r,s)=1$ and denoting $q=rs$, we have
$$ \sum_{n=1}^N c_r\left( n^2 \right) c_s\left( n^2 \right) 
= \sum_{n=1}^N c_q\left( n^2 \right) = \sum_{n=1}^N \sum_{d\mid(q,n^2)}\mu\left(\frac{q}{d}\right)d = \sum_{d\mid q}\mu\left(\frac{q}{d}\right)d\sum_{\substack{{1\leq n\leq N}\\{d\mid n^2}}} 1. $$
Now let $f(d)$ be the number of residue classes modulo $d$ whose square is zero modulo $d$. Then 
$$ \sum_{n=1}^N c_r\left( n^2 \right) c_s\left( n^2 \right) 
= \sum_{d\mid q}\mu\left(\frac{q}{d}\right)d f(d)\left(\frac{N}{d}+O(1)\right)
= N \sum_{d\mid q}\mu\left(\frac{q}{d}\right) f(d) + O_q(1),$$
whence
$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N c_r\left( n^2 \right) c_s\left( n^2 \right) 
= \sum_{d\mid q}\mu\left(\frac{q}{d}\right) f(d).$$
The right hand side is the multiplicative convolution $g:=\mu\ast f$ evaluated at $q$, in particular it is multiplicative in $q$. Hence it suffices to determine $g$ at prime powers $p^k$, which is straightforward:
$$ g(p^k) = f(p^k)-f(p^{k-1}) = p^{\lfloor\frac{k}{2}\rfloor}-p^{\lfloor\frac{k-1}{2}\rfloor}.$$
We infer that the sought mean value equals
$$ g(q) = \begin{cases}\phi(\sqrt{q}),&q=\square\\0,&q\neq\square\end{cases} \tag{$\ast$}$$
Note that under our initial assumptions, $q$ is a square if and only if both $r$ and $s$ are squares.

**Added.** In the general case, i.e. without the coprimality condition on $r$ and $s$, we can proceed as follows. The function $n\mapsto c_r(n^2)c_s(n^2)$ is periodic mod $[r,s]$, hence the mean value exists and equals
$$ h(r,s):=\frac{1}{[r,s]}\sum_{n=1}^{[r,s]}c_r(n^2)c_s(n^2). $$
This function satisfies the multiplicativity relation
$$ h(rr',ss') = h(r,s)h(r',s'),\qquad (rs,r's')=1, $$
as follows from the Chinese Remainder Theorem and the invariance property
$$ c_q(m)=c_q(km),\qquad (k,q)=1. $$
Therefore,
$$ h(r,s) = \prod_{p\mid rs}h(p^{v_p(r)},p^{v_p(s)}), $$
so that it suffices to evaluate $h(p^k,p^l)$ for any prime $p$ and any exponents $k,l\geq 0$. This is straightforward, given the explicit formulae for $c_{p^k}(m)$ [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan's_sum). In particular, for $l>k\geq 0$ we obtain
$$ h(p^k,p^l)=\phi(p^k)h(1,p^l)
=\begin{cases}\phi(p^k)\phi(p^{l/2}),&\text{$l$ even}\\0,&\text{$l$ odd}\end{cases}$$
which generalizes the explicit formula ($\ast$) above.

Comment: how do you make the jump: $\sum\limits_{n =1}^{N} 
c_r\left( n^2 \right)
c_s\left( n^2 \right) = \sum\limits_{n =1}^{N} 
c_q\left( n^2 \right)$ when $r \ne s$

Comment: I assume $(r,s)=1$, not just $r\neq s$. Then, $c_r(m)c_s(m)=c_{rs}(m)$ for all $m$.

Comment: I am not guaranteed (r,s)=1.  The outer summations which I left off are: $r=1 \to \infty$  and 
$s=1 \to \infty$

Comment: Computationally, I got the same result, \begin{align*}
\sum\limits_{n =1}^{N} 
c_r\left( n^2 \right)
c_s\left( n^2 \right) 
&= 
\begin{cases}
\phi\left( r \right) & r = s
\\
0 & r \ne s
\end{cases}
\end{align*} but now I can prove it. Thanks.

Comment: To keep the notation consistent: $\phi(r) = \varphi(r) = $ Euler's Totient function

Comment: Demonstrating the mean is zero when $(r,s) = d > 1$ is straight forward.

Comment: @JohnWashburn: I don't agree that the mean is zero when $(r,s)>1$. For example, if $r=p$ and $s=p^2$, where $p$ is a prime, then the mean value is $(p-1)^2$. This is because $c_p(n^2)c_{p^2}(n^2)$ equals zero for $p\nmid n$ and equals $\phi(p)\phi(p^2)$ when $p\mid n$.

Comment: I agree I made a mistake in the $(r,s) > 1$ case.  In general my assertion fails if $r \mid s$. I am working on it now.  Still the partial answer for $(r,s) =1$ is very helpful.

Comment: @JohnWashburn: My "Added" section contains the full answer. Well, I did not give the formula for $h(p^k,p^k)$, but this is straightforward to find.